# PHP Check Whether Current Time Greater Than 11:00

Tags: php, datetime

I Need A Help With Data Time. I am currently working with A Queue for Hospital.Queue is maintained by Booking of Appointments.What I want to do is I want to  maintain Queue based on current timing.If Current Time is less than 11:00 AM Queue should start from 11:00 AM else Queue should start from Current time.

Comment: This 11:00 AM Comes From MYSQL Db in 11:00:00. How To Convert The same to 11:00 AM?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if(date("G") >= 11)      // or >10
{
  // current time is greater than 11:00 AM
}
```

Where `G` parameter for `date` function stands for

> 24-hour format of an hour without leading zeros

[Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 3):

```
if(strtotime(date('H:i:s')) > strtotime(date('11:00:00'))){
  echo 'Greater than 11 AM';
}
else{
  echo 'Less than 11 AM';
}
```

Comment: What was that? That's a big time overkill

Comment: Also, `date` call is not needed for your second operand. That doesn't do anything, it just returns back `11:00:00`

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like following:

```
if (time() >= strtotime("11:00 AM")) 
{
  echo "Greater than 11:00 AM";
}
else
{
    echo "Less than 11:00 AM";
}
```

Comment: Why use 2 function calls when it can be done with one?

Comment: OK OK, I agrree your answer better mine, just alternative ;)

Comment: Nope I never said mine was better, just asked a question to learn :)

Comment: This is better for off hour times like "> 11:24 PM'. Yes?